# How I can multiply my each row of matrix separetly by matrix?

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication, array-broadcasting

Can't solve it without **for**, but I think it's not a good idea.

I want to implement ellipse throw multipling row of points(size 2xN), where each column is pair of (x,y), by matrix (size 2x2, because is 2d) and afterthat multiply by column (size Nx2), where each row is same pair of (x,y) like in a first 2xN-row.
Finally, I expect have Nx2 or 2xN vector, which will contain set of points.

Comment: You should add an example of what you're aiming for.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.